# Reactor (Spring Flux)

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux

Im using Spring Flux.
I need to assemble an Object from a different sources.
How can I be sure that both streams returned required data?

Like:

```
 public Mono<MyObject> createMyObject() {

        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

        someService.getSomeData().subscribe(myObject::setData);
        oneMoreService.getMoreData().subscribe(list -> {
            // myObject populate more fields
        });

        // how can I be sure that someData and moreData is populated, before we reach doSomeBusinessStuff method?
        return Mono.just(myObject);
    }

 public Result doSomeBusinessStuff(Mono<MyObject> myObject) {

        // make some other calculations with someData and moreData

    }
```

Comment: you should use `.doOnComplete(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can zip them.

```
return Mono.zip(someService.getSomeData(), oneMoreService.getMoreData())
        .map(t -> {              
            X data1 = t.getT1();
            Y data2 = t.getT2();

            MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
            //...
            return myObject;
        });
```

You can find information about it in the documentation.
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-